# Target an image by alt tag in jQuery to disable hyperlink

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target an image by it's alt tag to turn off an automatically generated hyperlink which is performed server side and that I can't edit.

The code I'm using is:

```
$('.ssImage a[title="test image"]').click(function(){return false;});
```

Which isn't working....

The HTML:

```
<div class="ssImage"><a href="/content/test.htm" title="test image"><img src="/content/test.jpg" alt="test image"/></a></div>
```

I can't target the div itself, as it'll affect other images with the same class on the page, so I need to find a way of specifying the image by alt or title.

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/GHfYG/

Comment: you can use as selector also the image alt/title if you want so and use .parent() to get the link around

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a `$(document).ready` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the selector is working fine, instead it's the `return false;` which is not preventing the click. Try this:

```
$('.ssImage a[title="test image"]').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: `return false;` works, too - even though `e.preventDefault()` is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

a working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/mnLr8/

```
$('.ssImage a[title="test image"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked the link');
});
```

pass the event to the function as e,  then e.preventDefault(); stops the click from being fired.